# Spring Jackson deserialization only picks the first item of an array

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I building an api rest with spring boot. I have a parent-child relationship in witch the child its an array of objects.

The problem is that deserialization only picks the first item of the array. Everything else seems to work fine. The parent and the child are pesisted in the database too.

I send something like this:

```
"user": {
  "name": "foo",
  "childs": [
    {
       "name": "bar",
        ....
    },
    {
       "name": "foobar",
        ....
    }
  ],
  ....
}
```

But got persisted this:

```
"user": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "foo",
  "childs": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "bar",
        ....
    }
  ],
  ....
}
```

Any clue on this?

## Update

Parent Entity:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
        property = "id",
        scope = User.class)
@Entity( name = "users" )
@Table( name = "users" )
public class User extends ModelEntity {
    
    Model's fields...
    ...

    @JsonView( value = {DTOViews.PrivateProfile.class, DTOViews.Owner.class} )
    @JsonManagedReference( value = "User-ProfessionalExperience" )
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private Set<ProfessionalExperience> professionalExperiences;
}
```

Child entity:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
    property = "id",
    scope = ProfessionalExperience.class)
@Entity
@Table( name = "professional_experiences")
public class ProfessionalExperience extends ModelEntity {

    Model's fields...
    ...

    @JsonBackReference( value = "User-ProfessionalExperience" )
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MappingJacksonValue create(@RequestBody @Valid User userToCreate, BindingResult result) {

    ...
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you show some actual code for this process please?

Comment: i need to see the class of `user`, and the class of `child`

Comment: @craigwor I updated with code. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally solved it. The issue comes from the relationship collection type and hasCode() / equals() methods.

All the entities in my model extend from "ModelEntity" class. This class provides id and record active fields for all extending models and a hasCode/equals method based on these fields. As the relationship between "User" and "ProfessionalExperience" is defined as a set, it can't store duplicated elements.

So, to tell jackson that the children are different elements, we need to override hasCode/equals in each model class with the fields defined in each one.